# No matter which groupView is selected, only one fragment is shown.

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView contained within a Navigation Drawer, and each group of the ExpandableListView should take the user to one of two fragments: AssignmentManagerFragment and SubjectManagerFragment. The third view, among the groups, is set to bring the user to SubjectManagerFragment, but for some reason *ALL* of them bring the user to AssignmentManagerFragment. Any idea why, or what can be done to fix it?

Here's my code:

```
drawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id){
            Fragment fragment;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager;
            Bundle args;
            switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new AssignmentManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(AssignmentManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                    if (drawerList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        drawerList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    } else {
                        drawerList.expandGroup(groupPosition, false);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                case 1:
                    fragment = new AssignmentManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(AssignmentManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                    if (drawerList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        drawerList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    } else {
                        drawerList.expandGroup(groupPosition, false);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                case 2:
                    fragment = new SubjectManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(SubjectManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    drawer.closeDrawer(drawerList);

                case 3:
                    fragment = new AssignmentManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(AssignmentManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                    if (drawerList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        drawerList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    } else {
                        drawerList.expandGroup(groupPosition, false);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                case 4:
                    fragment = new AssignmentManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(AssignmentManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                    if (drawerList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        drawerList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    } else {
                        drawerList.expandGroup(groupPosition, false);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot break statements after each case. There was nothing functionally wrong with onGroupClickListener; it was a simple coding mistake, but it can serve as a good example of rushed coding.